# How to share an app with friends and family only

Tags: ios, applications, development

I am currently developing an iOS app for one of my family members. The only thing is, I do not want it on the App Store.

How would I be able to share this with my family member? I know that I could use Cydia impactor or with a personal developer certificate, but this would require signing every few days if I remember correctly?

Comment: Are you enrolled in any of the paid developer programs?

Comment: Yes, however, don't you need to have an enterprise @NimeshNeema account to add other people onto your team? Also TestFlight expires after so many days too.

Comment: You don't need an enterprise account. Just an individual paid developer account will do. The easiest way for you to distribute app to friends and family is via TestFlight. I'll elaborate in answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you are registered as a paid Apple developer (either as individual or an organisation), you can use [TestFlight](https://testflight.apple.com) to easily share your app with friends and family. You'll need the Apple ID of the person and can add them as a tester.

You can add upto 1000 Apple IDs as tester under TestFlight and release the app. The individual members can install the app on their personal devices.

Unlike using certificates and asking members to share their device UDIDs, this approach is seamless for both the parties. The shared app build remains valid for upto 90 days from the date of publishing. This process also makes it easy to push app updates.

The family members (testers) just need to have [TestFlight](https://itunes.apple.com/app/testflight/id899247664) app installed on their device to receive app builds and updates. This also works great for Apple TV apps.

Go through the [TestFlight - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) documentation to learn more.

Comment: So I'm forced to do an update every 90 days (excluding review time)? There not a way of bypassing the 90 day limit?

Comment: @iProgram Sorry, I am not aware if this is configurable or of any up-to-date information. I'm unable to find anything in the documentation at the moment. You should be able to check this by attempting to publish a build via TestFlight.

Comment: @iProgram 4 years after. Did you use TestFlight? It is easy accessible for friends and family? I want to do the same and have some elderly people in my group having trouble if it gets too technical. Especially, the 90 days only seems very annoying to me. How was your experience?